# Leaving hot chicken on the counter

Tags: food-safety, chicken

I accidentally placed my hot chicken on the counter for 1 hour and 15 minutes last night before placing it in Tupperware and storing it in the fridge for lunch today.

Before people reference the FDA, I see it says two hours. My question is: does this number change since my chicken was right out of the oven and steaming hot?

Comment: Assuming the temp was above the danger zone when you took it out of the oven, the difference would be that the chicken was not in the danger zone for the entire 1.25 hours. (It took some time for the temp to drop into the danger zone.)

Comment: For some more information on basic food safety, read also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info